# On the Construction of Random Variables with Prescribed Joint Distributions

Tags: probability, measure-theory

In Chapter 10 of Folland's Real Analysis, he gives an interesting way of constructing random variables with prescribed joint distributions. Let $\mathbb{R}^*=\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ be the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$. In the following theorem, a random variable is allowed to assume the value $\infty$ and a Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is regared as a Borel measure on $(\mathbb{R}^*)^n$ that assigns measure zero to $(\mathbb{R}^*)^n-\mathbb{R}^n$.

> 10.18 Theorem: Let $A$ be an arbitrary nonempty set, and suppose that for each ordered $n$-tuple of distinct elements of $A$ $(n\in \mathbb{N})$ we are given a Borel probability measure $P_{(\alpha_1,\cdots, \alpha_n)}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying
> $$\text{if $\sigma$ is a permutation of $\{1,\cdots, n\}$, then } dP_{(\alpha_{\sigma(1)},\cdots, \alpha_{\sigma(n)})}(x_{\sigma(1)},\cdots, x_{\sigma(n)})=dP_{(\alpha_1,\cdots, \alpha_n)}(x_1,\cdots, x_n)$$
> and
> $$\text{if $k<n$ and $E\in \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^k}$, then }
> P_{(\alpha_1,\cdots, \alpha_k)}(E)=P_{(\alpha_1,\cdots, \alpha_n)}(E\times \mathbb{R}^{n-k})$$
> Then there is a unique Radon probability measure $P$ on the compact Hausdorff space $\Omega=(\mathbb{R}^*)^A$ such that $P_{(\alpha_1,\cdots, \alpha_n)}$ is the joint distribution of $X_{\alpha_1},\cdots, X_{\alpha_n}$, where $X_{\alpha}:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^*$ is the $\alpha$th coordinate function.

I understand the proof of this theorem. However, I am not satisfied with the random variables generated by this theorem because they assume the value $\infty$ and are not true random variables. I want to know whether $(\mathbb{R}^A, \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^A}, P|_{\mathbb{R}^A})$ (where $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^A}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $P|_{\mathbb{R}^A}$ is the restriction of $P$ onto $\mathbb{R}^A$) forms a sample space such that the coordinate functions on it are true random variables with prescribed joint distributions.  And it suffices to prove the following statement:
$$P((\mathbb{R}^*)^A-\mathbb R^A)=0\text{ or equivalently }P(\mathbb{R}^A)=1$$